# Java Persistence Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException with EntityManager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence

The below piece of code in try block is throwing null pointer exception inside eclipse link SDK class if getResultList() is called persistence query object when it is formed with actual database query is empty. In this case dbQuery.toString() is empty in one of the cases.

```
EntityManager entityManager = this.getEntityManager();
List resultList;
try {
  resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(dbQuery.toString()).getResultList();
} finally {
  if (entityManager != null) {
    entityManager.close();
  }
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
    Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: DataReadQuery()
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.setCallFromStatement(StatementQueryMechanism.java:392) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.prepareExecuteSelect(StatementQueryMechanism.java:280) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.prepare(DataReadQuery.java:263) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:666) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    ... 355 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException: 
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: DataReadQuery()
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1596) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:685) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:615) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:872) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]
    ... 345 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: DataReadQuery()
```

Why is this ? Is this expected ? I am expecting that library should have handled this case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is null? You are only showing the javax.persistence.PersistenceException, not the internal NPE stack trace.

Comment: @Chris pls find the updated stack trace. If i have to point exactly.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473) ~[eclipselink-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3]

I might be wrong here. I am not trying to find where exactly it is going null, but instead wanted to know if this is valid/invalid case.

Comment: or the question can be "is it expected to get exception when the query doesn't actually return any results" ?

Comment: No, an NPE is not expected. They are generally considered bugs. But you shouldn't be passing in an empty string - what is your application expecting the DB to do with this? That EclipseLink threw an NPE is much better than wasting resources hitting the DB and is something your app should never have allowed. File a bug for eclipseLink to validate these strings to avoid the NPE, but seems low priority and something your app shouldn't have allowed.